# Redirect to the page only if the credentials are correct

Tags: jsp, session

I am facing problem in maintaining the session. I have two files `login.jsp` and `welcome.jsp`.

If the credentials in the `login.jsp` are provided correctly, It redirects to `welcome.jsp`. But, the problem I am facing right now is if I change the filename in the url, I am able to access `welcome.jsp` without any credentials.

I want that the file `welcome.jsp` should only be accessed when the right credentials are provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** When user logs in, store *Username* and *Password* in a `Session` attribute.

```
session.setAttribute("username", <Username variable>);
session.setAttribute("password", <Password variable>);
```

**2)** Then in your `welcome.jsp` do this:

```
String username = "";
String password = "";

username = session.getAttribute("username");
password = session.getAttribute("password");

if(username.equals("") || password.equals("") || username == null || password == null)
{
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```